# Count number of unique values containing text

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that counts the number of cells in a column that contains the string, `"ABC-QR"`:

```
Ctr = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet1.Range("D4:D1500"), "*ABC-QR*")
EU.Cells(16, 3) = Ctr
```

I used `"ABC-QR"` because that's the part of the data that doesn't change. The true data that's in those cells is, for example, `"ABC-QR00012345"`, or whatever number it may have. I would like to modify my code to *not include duplicates* when it's counting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Firstly, you must enable 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' from within Tools --> References within the Visual Basic Editor.

You assign the data from the worksheet into an array; then import everything which fits the string criteria, and isn't a duplicate, into a [dictionary](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/187234). You can check for duplicates in the dictionary using the [`.Exists` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171995(v=office.11).aspx).

**EDIT:** As noted by @Zev in the comments, you don't even need to use the `.Exists` method. You can just assign the array element to the key of the dictionary, and assign the item value as 1. Any duplicate values from the Array will overwrite the previous key, so duplicates will automatically be dealt with.

Once everything which isn't a duplicate has been imported into the dictionary, you can then use the `.Count` property on the dictionary. This will tell you how many records fit your string criteria, and are not duplicates, within the range passed into the array.

```
Option Explicit
Sub countNonDuplicates()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim myValues() As Variant
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    myValues = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lRow, 1))

    For i = 1 To UBound(myValues, 1)
        If InStr(myValues(i, 1), "ABC-QR") Then dict(myValues(i,1)) = 1 'arbitrary value
    Next i
    MsgBox (dict.Count)
End Sub
```

The above currently gets the last row of `Column A` and then takes the range and assigns it to the array. If you wish to use a different column, then update the following statements with the column number required (example below now uses `Column D`)

```
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
myValues = Range(Cells(1, 4), Cells(lRow, 4))
```

Also it's currently performing the above on `Sheets(1)`. Change the worksheet number to what you require.

> On 100,000 records this took 0.2 seconds to produce the count.

Comment: Please correct me if my understanding is wrong, so basically what I need to do is put the range of cells where the data is and from the dictionary I can check if there are duplicates and exclude them from the `.Count`? Apologies for my confusions i'm fairly new with VBA and im just starting to work on my first full on project with it. I definitely need to check up on the Dictionary Object for VBA.

Comment: Yeah, basically: range into Array, then items from the array where **a)** it matches the pattern "ABC-QR" and **b)** the full string has not already been added into the dictionary, will then be added to the dictionary. So you're not excluding anything from the count, but rather excluding them from being added to the dictionary in the first instance. Yeah it's worth reading up on dictionaries and arrays; they're extremely powerful :)

Comment: I understand. And yes, I will definitely read up on dictionaries and arrays :) But, the thing is, "ABC-QR" is not the whole value of the cell, it differs everytime, there might just be duplicates like two "ABC-QR0123456" but it can also have the value of "ABC-QR567890". Is this unclear in some ways? I feel like I'm not explaining it good enough. lol. sorry.

Comment: So if there's two "ABC-QR0123456" and one "ABC-WR567890" in the range, then using the `.Count` property would return 2. It counts all values containing "ABC-QR" but effectively removes duplicates. Give it a test and you will see. Let me know if you have any other questions :).

Comment: Alright :) Gimme a couple of minutes I'll give it a try

Comment: Wow this works beautifully! :D Thanks mate! Btw, can I ask you a couple of more questions via private message?

Comment: Glad to help! Sure, go for it.

Comment: Is there a way I can reach you in private @lturner?

Comment: [Discussion room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84319/discussion-between-lturner-and-synthaxe).

Comment: There's no need for an explicit check if the item exists. Instead of the `If Not dict.Exists ..Then`, you can simply say `dict(myValues(i, 1)) = 1` (because the value is unimportant).

Comment: Good shout @Zev. I will consider that going forward, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This array formula should do the trick:

```
EU.Cells(16,3).FormulaArray = "=SUM(IF(ISERROR(FIND(""ABC-QR"",D4:D1500)),0,1/(COUNTIF(D4:D1500,D4:D1500))))"
```

Since it's an array formula, it will operate on each cell in your range in turn and look for your text (`FIND("ABC-QR",D4:D1500)`). If it's not found, it returns `0` to the running `SUM()`. If it is found, it uses the value `1/count`, where `count` is the number of times the cell value being tested exists in your range.

Comment: Very nice.  I believe you could stick this in an `Application.Evaluate` to avoid the formula actually being output on the sheet (and possibly changing in the future).  Or a quick `EU.Cells(16,3) = EU.Cells(16,3)` to force the formula back to value.